# Pipe Right pass-through operator PipeThrough

Tags: f#, currying

I have declared the following operator to help make my curried code a bit more legible

Pipe-Through allows a value to be passed through a method and continue out the other side. I think it helps make my code more succinct.

```
let (|>!) x f = x |> f |> ignore; x
```

Example of use

```
let y = x |> transform
y |> logger.LogInformation
y
|> process
|> return
```

Now becomes

```
x 
|> transform 
|>! logger.LogInformation 
|> process 
|> return
```

Is this useful or have I reinvented the wheel

Comment: You may want to see **computation expressions**. It is not the same thing but there is a more idiomatic way of logging and using other functions with side effect only.

Comment: @ozgur I specifically wanted a flyweight fire & forget for use with something like ILogger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is useful and like all good inventions it has been independently made by others as well.

Scott Wlaschin called it `tee`: https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/rop/

The proposed operator is `|>!`:

```
let inline    tee f v   = f v ; v
let inline  (|>!) v f   = f v ; v
let inline  (>>!) g f   = g >> fun v -> f v ; v    /// composition

(5 * 8) |> tee (printfn "value = %d") |> doSomethingElse
(5 * 8) |>!     printfn "value = %d"  |> doSomethingElse
```

This definition is slightly different than yours as it does not use `ignore`.

Thanks for sharing!

Comment: The ignore allows you to pass thru a function - of course that may be a side-effect of not having got to this earlier when writing those functions.